# Trying to combine plots

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to combine two plots

```
rho0bar = rho0 - k11^2 mu0/w^2;
rho1bar = rho1 - k11^2 c66/w^2 - k11^2 c64^2/(w^2 c44);
rho2bar = rho2 - k11^2 mu2/w^2;
R1 = (rho1bar (rho2bar/mu2)^(1/2) + 
 rho2bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2))/(rho2bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2) - 
 rho1bar (rho2bar/mu2)^(1/2));
R0 = (rho0bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2) + 
 rho1bar (rho0bar/mu0)^(1/2))/(rho1bar (rho0bar/mu0)^(1/2) - 
 rho0bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2));
```

The first plot

```
plot1 = Plot[
Chop[R0 /. {rho1 -> 3000, k11 -> 1.2, c66 -> 2 10^9, 
 c64 -> 3.1 10^9, c44 -> 2.9 10^9, rho2 -> 3456, rho0 -> 3556, 
 mu2 -> 2345, mu0 -> 2500}], {w, 10^4, 10^5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the second

```
plot2 = Plot[
 Chop[R1 /. {rho1 -> 3000, k11 -> 1.2, c66 -> 2 10^9, 
 c64 -> 3.1 10^9, c44 -> 2.9 10^9, rho2 -> 3456, rho0 -> 3556, 
 mu2 -> 2345, mu0 -> 2500}], {w, 10^4, 10^5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

with

```
Show[plot1,plot2]
```

But I get the error that it cannot combine plots. How can I do this?

Also, I wondering, how would I plot a combination of these functions for example

```
R0*R1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange! I don't get an error when I run your unmodified code - can you elaborate on the error message you receive? Also, what version of Mathematica are you using? I've included an example of how to plot the combined functions in this [cloud notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a65a49ba-c0d7-4eb2-8476-face813492d6), please check it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
rho0bar = rho0 - k11^2 mu0/w^2;
rho1bar = rho1 - k11^2 c66/w^2 - k11^2 c64^2/(w^2 c44);
rho2bar = rho2 - k11^2 mu2/w^2;
paras = {rho1 -> 3000, k11 -> 1.2, c66 -> 2 10^9, c64 -> 3.1 10^9, 
   c44 -> 2.9 10^9, rho2 -> 3456, rho0 -> 3556, mu2 -> 2345, mu0 -> 2500};
R1 = (rho1bar (rho2bar/mu2)^(1/2) + 
      rho2bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2))/(rho2bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2) - 
      rho1bar (rho2bar/mu2)^(1/2)) /. paras;
R0 = (rho0bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2) + 
      rho1bar (rho0bar/mu0)^(1/2))/(rho1bar (rho0bar/mu0)^(1/2) - 
      rho0bar (rho1bar/c44)^(1/2)) /. paras;

Plot[{R0, R1}, {w, 10^4, 10^5}]

Plot[R0*R1, {w, 10^4, 10^5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Hi, the combined plot doesn't seem to give the correct result.

Comment: @user62680 Then you should check your equations. `Plot` command will plot whatever you provide to it.